# Select2 in Bootstrap with Dependent/Chained autocomplete List. Did not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create Dependent/Chained Dropdown List (with auto-complete) with Bootstrap4 and Django.

I'm trying to use this [solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EapNPo?editors=101).

Everything works fine if the forms are dropdown List.

```
<select id="id_country" name="country" class="form-control" >
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">Colombia</option>
    <option value="2">Rusia</option>
</select>
<select id="id_city" name="city" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1" class="1">Bogotá</option>
    <option value="2" class="2">Moscú</option>
    <option value="3" class="2">San Petersburgo</option>
    <option value="4" class="1">Valledupar</option>
</select>
```

But when I try to set the autocomplete to the first field, the second field stops working (stops responding).

My code (after changes) looks like this:

```
<select id="id_country" name="country" class="form-control" data-toggle="select" title="Country" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Country">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">Colombia</option>
    <option value="2">Rusia</option>
</select>
<select id="id_city" name="city" class="form-control">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1" class="1">Bogotá</option>
    <option value="2" class="2">Moscú</option>
    <option value="3" class="2">San Petersburgo</option>
    <option value="4" class="1">Valledupar</option>
</select>
```

Why the solution stops working after adding additional parameters to the select field. Is it possible to add some simple JavaScript code in template that will run it again so that the second drop down field react properly again.