# Django, how to filter a form based on another one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following django app structure:

models.py

```
class CodiceCommessa(models.Model):
    codice_commessa=models.ForeignKey(Informazioni_Generali, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Informazioni_Generali(models.Model):
    codice_commessa= models.CharField('Codice', unique=True, max_length=5)
    data_registrazione=models.DateField()
```

forms.py

```
class CodiceCommessaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CodiceCommessa
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
def altri_costi_commessa(request):
    cod=[]

    if request.method == 'POST':
        year = request.POST['year']

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = CodiceCommessaForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             cod = form.save()
    else :
        form = CodiceCommessaForm()
```

In my template I have set the form. All works, but I want that, when I select a year, automatically django show me only the `codice_commessa` that match the year in the field `data_registrazione`.

Is it possibile to get it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django dependent select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706639/django-dependent-select)

Comment: On top of what @ArakkalAbu is linking (which are older custom solutions), [Django Autocomplete Light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form) is the de-facto tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your question properly  but for searching anything from database you can use following syntex
x = labor.objects.filter('COMPRESSION STATEMENTS').value('KEY FOR SEARCHING')
x = labor.objects.filter(PhoneNumber=MobNo).values('AdharNo')

any only for searching object use
x = labor.objects.filter(PhoneNumber=MobNo)