# Extract related fields or Keys instead of value using request.POST.get method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, request

**I have 2 tables in `Django` `db.sqlite3` database both having `state_id` as a common field on the basis of which I had to map the districts for respective states in dropdown using Jquery**

***state_database***

```
    id   state_id  state_name
    3      3          Uttarakhand
    2      2          Punjab
    1      1          Haryana
```

***district_database***

```
    id   state_id  district_id district_name
    1        1         1         Sonipat
    2        1         2         Rohtak
    3        1         3         Amabala
    4        1         4         Sirsa
    5        2         5         Amritsar
    6        2         6         Ludhiana
    7        3         7         Pantnagar
    8        3         8         Almora
```

For Doing so, I had to assign the `common field / state_id` as value in ***HTML*** like `value= '{{state.state_id}}'`

```
                <select class="form-control" id="state_from_dropdown" name="state_from_dropdown" aria-label="...">
                    <option selected disabled="true"> --- Select State --- </option>
                    {% for state in StatesInDropdown %}
                    <option value= '{{state.state_id}}'> {{state.state_name}} </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>

                <select class="form-control" id="district_from_dropdown" name="district_from_dropdown" aria-label="...">
                    <option selected disabled="true"> --- Select District --- </option>
                    {% for disitrict in DistrictsInDropdown %}
                    <option value= '{{disitrict.state_id}}'> {{disitrict.district_name}} </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
```

***Views.py***

```
def inputconfiguration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        StateName=request.POST.get('state_from_dropdown')
        DistrictName=request.POST.get('district_from_dropdown','')
        print(StateName, DistrictName)
    return render(request, 'configure_inputs.html')
```

**Instead of Getting Actual Fields/Names which appears in the dropdown, I get the values of ID's, but I want the names of states and districts instead of their ID's**

***models.py***

```
class state_name(models.Model):
    state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1.0), MaxValueValidator(100.0)])
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class district_name(models.Model):
    state_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1.0), MaxValueValidator(100.0)])
    district_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1.0), MaxValueValidator(100.0)])
    district_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('inputconfiguration', views.inputconfiguration, name='inputconfiguration')
]
```

***JQuery*** for Dropdown of `Districts` based on `States`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var states = $('#state_from_dropdown');
        districts = $('#district_from_dropdown');
    districtOptions = districts.find('option');
    // console.log("$option_list", districtOptions)
    states.on('change',function(){
        districts.html(districtOptions.filter('[value="'+this.value+'"]'));
    }).trigger('change');
    });
```

***How to do so?***

Comment: I deleted my answer, since I missed something very important.  Sorry.  Bottom line, you must give the district options different values than the state options.  Your JQuery must target the district options in a different manner than using `this.value`.  Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25710112/10951070) for a good way to approach this.

Comment: Sure @raphael, I would try that. Although your answer was brief and had information. You might have kept it. & Thanks for your time.